# Async loading of components in react-virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-virtualized

I have a react-virtualized masonry grid implemented in a component as follows:

```
const MasonrySubmissionRender = (media: InputProps) => {

    function cellRenderer({ index, key, parent, style }: MasonryCellProps) {
        //const size = (media.submissionsWithSizes && media.submissionsWithSizes.length > index) ? media.submissionsWithSizes[index].size : undefined
        //const height = size ? (columnWidth * (size.height / size.width)) : defaultHeight;
        function getCard(index: number, extraProps: any) {
            var Comp = media.cardElement ? media.cardElement : SubmissionCard

            return <Comp submission={media.media[index]} {...media.customCardProps} />
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <CellMeasurer
                    cache={cache}
                    index={index}
                    key={key}
                    parent={parent}>
                    <div style={style}>
                        {getCard(index, media.customCardProps)}
                    </div>
                </CellMeasurer>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Masonry
            overscanByPixels={1000}
            autoHeight={false}
            cellCount={media.media.length}
            cellMeasurerCache={cache}
            cellPositioner={cellPositioner}
            cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
            height={900}
            width={900}
        />
    );
};
```

It renders a list of fairly complicated components which contain an array of chips, css animations, etc.

Due to this rendering is very slow even with react-virtualized.

I'd like to implement a system like in imgur.com where the component itself won't necessary load immediately displaying only a silhouette while I can have the component preparing to render in the background.

I know there's a way to swap out the component during scrolling butt his hides all components including ones which have already rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all react-virtualized cell/row renderers, [masonry's cell render](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Masonry.md#cellrenderer) is passed an `isScrolling` property. When the masonry is scrolling you can render a place holder instead of the cell content:

```
if (isScrolling) return ( 
  <div>placeholder</div>
);
```

In addition, you are recreating all functions whenever the stateless component is rerendred. This causes an extra overhead for the garbage collector, and might also cause components to rerender unnecessarily.

Convert the component to a class component. The `cellRenderer` should be an instance method (use class properties or bind in constructor). The `getCard` can be a class method, or you can extract it from the component, and pass the `media` when you call the function.

Your code should be something like this (not tested):

```
function getCard(media: InputProps, index: number) {
  var Comp = media.cardElement ? media.cardElement : SubmissionCard

  return <Comp submission = {
      media.media[index]
    } { ...media.customCardProps }
  />
}

class MasonrySubmissionRender extends React.Component {

  cellRenderer = ({
    index,
    key,
    parent,
    style,
    isScrolling
  }: MasonryCellProps) => {
    if (isScrolling) return ( 
      <div>placeholder</div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
          <CellMeasurer
              cache={cache}
              index={index}
              key={key}
              parent={parent}>
              <div style={style}>
                  {getCard(media, index)}
              </div>
          </CellMeasurer>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {   
    return (
      <Masonry
        overscanByPixels={1000}
        autoHeight={false}
        cellCount={media.media.length}
        cellMeasurerCache={cache}
        cellPositioner={cellPositioner}
        cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        height={900}
        width={900}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: upon further investigation I found out there's a bug in my code or react-virtualized which causes components inside of a masonry to all load at once taking away the react-virtualized beenfits.

I posted my findings on the react-virtualized git.

Having said that your comment has been very helpful in getting me to understand how to write performant code.

I do have a question to follow up on the 'isScrolling' solution, is there a way to know which components have been already rendered so that I know not to put a stump component in its place?

Comment: react-virtualized will remove components that are not in the view or it's buffer, so it's mostly not necessary to know what was rendered. However, as long as items are in the view, you might want to show them instead of a placeholder. You can pass the  'isScrolling' to the components, and each component can maintain it's "rendered" state, and decide to render it's content or a placeholder using a flag.